# Jekyll site.categories.keys returns nothing

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have the following code in Jekyll and it doesn't output what I expect.

```
{% assign x1= site.categories %}
<div id="x1">{{ x1 | inspect }}</div>

{% assign x2= site.categories.keys %}
<div id="x2">{{ x2 | inspect }}</div>
```

Output:

```
<div id="x1">{"abc"=&gt;[<post: demo-post1="">, <post: demo-post2="">, <post: demo-post3="">,  .... </div>

<div id="x2"></div>
```

Or a prettier version of "x1"

```
{abc"=>[, , , , , , ], "def"=>[, , , , , , , ], ....
```

So, it there's data in `site.categories` and it seems to be a `Hash` but `x2` has no value... Why? I was expecting it to print `"abc", "def", ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is not ruby, it's Liquid. The way variables are evaluated is different.

`{{ site.categories }}` or `{{ site['categories'] }}` will return values if their keys are present in the `Liquid::Context` ([see liquid 3.x code here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/variable_lookup.rb#L41)).

If no matching key is found (like for `{{ site.categories.keys }}`), liquid tries to send a command on the object ([see](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/variable_lookup.rb#L54)), but command list is limited to `size, first and last` ([see](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/variable_lookup.rb#L4)).

This is true for Liquid 2.x and 3.x.

If you want all the categories names in an array, you can do :

```
{% comment %}create an empty array{% endcomment %}
{% assign catNames = "" | split: "/" %}
{% for c in site.categories %}
  {% assign catNames = catNames | push: c[0] %}
{% endfor %}
```

All categories names are now in `catNames`.